# My AJAX call is not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a simple JavaScript code like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest, action = "action=latest", page = "http://192.168.1.115/wp-content/themes/HSV%20Saints/setphoto.php";
    xhr.open("POST", page, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application-x-www-formurlencoded");
    xhr.send(action);

    xhr.onload = function(){
            console.log("XHR Onload");
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(action);
    }
```

I have a PHP script like this:

```
<?php

$action = $_POST['action'];
echo $action;
echo 'Test message';
?>
```

The $action variable is not showing up, but the 'Test message' is (in the console). I don't understand why it can't send var action

Comment: Any reason you're rolling your own ajax handler, and not using jquery? The entirety of your js code could be reduced to `$.post(page, {action:'latest'}, function(data) { console.log(data); });`

Comment: Stackoverflow search 'Ajax not working' -> 51,296 results

Comment: try this `echo $action.'Test message';`

Answer (score 1):

Send method of XMLHttpRequest takes data as argument only in case of POST request.
Look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest
For GET, your action should be part of URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try var_dump ($_POST); in php code to see what you are getting in there.

Then you will come to know what is going wrong.